# Error when running PathCreateTool in puppet

Tags: java, puppet

Can someone help me in fixing the error I am facing while creating PathCreatetTool on windows through puppet scripting.

Error:

> could not find or load main class com.ibm.cm.tools.PathCreateTool

I have tried to put the command in a .bat file and run, works fine on commandline but not through puppet.

java

```
 com.ibm.content.cm.tools.PathModelCreate -r DIUG -u NUHICMAD -p nuh1cm8d -o SCHEMA=NUHIE -a Doc_Services -z true
```

Tried to set sys environmental variables as well, doesn't work for me.

```
CMCMIS_HOME=D:\IBM\ECMClient\configure\explodedformat\cmcmis\WEB-INF\classes
```

I tried merging `setuptoolscmdline.bat` command and `pathcreate` command all works fine only on cmd line not through puppet.

gave classpath as below but still no luck:

java

```
-classpath "D:\IBM\ECMClient\configure\explodedformat\cmcmis\WEB-INF\lib" com.ibm.content.cm.tools.PathModelCreate -r DIUG -u NUHICMAD -p nuh1cm8d -o SCHEMA=NUHIE -a Doc_Services -z true
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve